# Find error in abstract algebra proof

Tags: abstract-algebra

I suspect that the proof below is flawed. I did not use the hypothesis "$\ker(h) \subseteq \ker(k)$" when proving sufficiency.

**Lemma.** $ $ Let $G$, $H$, $K$ be groups, let $h : G \to H$ and $k : G \to K$ be homomorphisms, and suppose that $h$ is surjective. In order for there to exist a homomorphism $f : H \to K$ such that $f \circ h = k$, it is necessary and sufficient that $\ker(h) \subseteq \ker(k)$. The homomorphism $f$ is then unique.

*Necessity*.$\ $ If there is a homomorphism $f$ such that $f \circ h = k$, and if $h(x) = e$, then $$k(x) = f(h(x)) = f(e) = e.$$

*Sufficiency*.$\ $ There exists a section $s : H \to G$ of $h$, so that $h \circ s = I_H$. Then $h \mid s(H) = s^{-1}$, so $s$ is a homomorphism. Choose $f = k \circ s$.

*Uniqueness*.$\ $ If $f, g : H \to K$ are homomorphisms such that $f \circ h = k = g \circ h$, then $f = k \circ s = g$.

Comment: Where is $g$ defined? Do you mean $k$?

Comment: Yes, that's a typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is an error when you say that $h$ has a section. Consider the surjection $\Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}/2$. It doesn't have a section since there are no nontrivial maps $\Bbb{Z}/2 \to \Bbb{Z}$.

Now, if you want to prove it, just realise that $H\cong G/ker(h)$ and $h$ is the quotient map. Then use the universal property of the quotient group.

Comment: Nice answer, +1. Just to spell this out more: $h$ might have a set-theoretic right inverse, but there's no guarantee that the map you get will be a homomorphism. This is concretely realized in the example given via the fact that every homomorphism from a torsion group into a torsion free group is trivial.

Comment: Yep that's exactly right. For sets every surjective map has a section, but not for groups.